# Regex to get data between comma separated values

Tags: python, regex

I am receiving a dynamic string with varying separators and wanted to get the data separated using regex.

```
s = abc(x, y), def(x, y)
s1 = abc(x,y), def(x, y)
s2 = abc(x,y),def(x,y)
s3 = abc(x, y),def(x, y)
```

I am expecting the data to be as below in group(1) and group(2), with or without spaces between x and y

```
group1 = abc(x, y)
group2 = def(x, y)
```

I tried to use `(.*)\),\s(.*)` but don't seem to get expected output. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I am able to resolve space issue using ```(.*)\),\s*(.*)``` but still need to find a way to get closing bracket for 'abc'

Comment: Could you post a sample data on which RegEx is to be applied as well as your expected output.

Comment: expecting ```abc(x, y)``` and ```def(x, y)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This RegEx will work:

```
(\w+\s*\(\s*\w+\s*,\s*\w+\s*\))\s*,\s*(\w+\s*\(\s*\w+\s*,\s*\w+\s*\))
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/vBwOIa/1).

Answer (score 0):

I started with [Ankits answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63717524/10009545) but used named groups and back referencing to ensure the name of the parameters are always the same in both `abc` and `def`:

```
.*? (?P<func0>abc)\s*\(\s*(?P<arg0>\w+)\s*,\s*(?P<arg1>\w+)\s*\)\s*,\s*(?P<func1>def)\s*\(\s*\2\s*,\s*\3\s*\)
```

By doing so the construction of your expected output becomes more readable:

```
group1 = \g<func0>(\g<arg0>, \g<arg1>)\ngroup2 = \g<func1>(\g<arg0>, \g<arg1>)
```

output as in [demo example](https://regex101.com/r/vBwOIa/3):

```
group1 = abc(x, y)
group2 = def(x, y)
group1 = abc(x, y)
group2 = def(x, y)
group1 = abc(x, y)
group2 = def(x, y)
group1 = abc(x, y)
group2 = def(x, y)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your problem too well but you might not need regex. To me it looks like you can grab them with

```
arr = s_n.split(',') ## This will separate into something like 
                     ## ["abc(x,y)", "  def(x,y)"]
arr = [element.strip() for element in arr] ## This will remove leading and 
                                           ## trailing white space for uniformity.
```

After that you have an array where the functions are separated and all extraneous white space has been stripped.